# Angular test case to test keyup event

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jestjs, rxjs, jasmine

Below mentioned code is working fine. which basically merge two events, merge them and do some operation on an input field. The problem is, I am not able to mock or write test cases for this code. Can anyone help me with this? I am using angular 12.

```
<input #myname value="John Doe">


ngAfterViewInit() {
const scrollEvents$ = fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, 'blur');
const keyEvents$ = fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
  filter((e: KeyboardEvent) => e.keyCode === 13)
);
    
const allEvents$ = merge(scrollEvents$, keyEvents$);
allEvents$
  .pipe(
    takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$),
    map((evt: any) => evt.target.value),
    distinctUntilChanged()
  )
  .subscribe((text: string) => {
     this.data = text;
  });
```

}

[Stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-delp26?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

Answer (score 0):

You'll have a much easier time writing tests if you use event binding, [like this](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-zmiqkg?file=src/app/app.component.html). Then you can write unit tests against the method, and/or E2E tests against the whole interaction.

Answer (score 0):

What I tend to do in general is to create "light" components and "fat" services.

In this case, this would mean to isolate the `pipe` logic into a service which is then passed via dependency injection into the component, something like this

```
export class AppService {
  constructor() {}

  allEvents(
    scrollEvents$: Observable<any>,
    keyEvents$: Observable<any>,
    unsubscribe$: Observable<any>
  ) {
    return merge(scrollEvents$, keyEvents$).pipe(
      takeUntil(unsubscribe$),
      map((evt: any) => {
        return evt.target.value;
      }),
      distinctUntilChanged()
    );
  }
}


  ngAfterViewInit() {
    const scrollEvents$ = fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, 'blur');
    const keyEvents$ = fromEvent(this.input.nativeElement, 'keyup').pipe(
      filter((e: KeyboardEvent) => e.keyCode === 13)
    );
    // creating other input observables...

    const allEvents$ = merge(scrollEvents$, keyEvents$);
    allEvents$
      .pipe(
        takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$),
        map((evt: any) => evt.target.value),
        distinctUntilChanged()
      )
      .subscribe((text: string) => {
        console.log(text);
      });
  }
```

Now you can more easily test the service `MyService` which is where most of the logic resides.